# Java Need Help To Get Print To All String

Tags: java, methods

guys i need help with this code 
i need to print all string by command (PrintAllStudents) i made the command but i didn't make it print all student it just print the lastest student added im learning java
here is my test class :

```
package com.tj;

public class Student {

    private int StudentId;
    private String StudentName;

    public void AddStudent(int StudentId, String StudentName){
    this.StudentId = StudentId;
    this.StudentName = StudentName;
    }
    public void PrintAllStudents() {
        System.out.println("Id : " + StudentId);
        System.out.println("StudentName : " + StudentName);

    }
}
```

and my test class :

```
package com.tj;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s = new Student();
        s.AddStudent(1, "Walied");
        s.AddStudent(2, "Ayman");
        s.AddStudent(3, "Mostafa");
        s.PrintAllStudents();
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to debug your code and you'll see that you're not storing all students. You're simply rewriting one.

Comment: You need a List of Students, now you are just giving your one student s a new id and renaming him.

Comment: You should really follow Java naming convention. Methods and variable start with lower case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend renaming your variables and methods to lower Camel Case: studentName, studentId, printAllStudents() to avoid confusion with classes like Student, String.

http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Currently your class `Student` holds two variables:

```
private int StudentId;
private String StudentName;
```

Your method `AddStudent(int StudentId, String StudentName)` assigns new values to those two variables:

```
this.StudentId = StudentId;
this.StudentName = StudentName;
```

Each time you call AddStudent() you assign new values. That's why you only see the id and name of the last student.

What you could do is create multiple Student objects in your test class, each object will hold it's own id and name variables:

```
Student s1 = new Student();
s1.AddStudent(1, "Walied");

Student s2 = new Student();
s2.AddStudent(2, "Ayman");

Student s3 = new Student();
s3.AddStudent(3, "Mostafa");

s1.PrintAllStudents();
s2.PrintAllStudents();
s3.PrintAllStudents();
```

You could rename your methods so it would look a bit more understandable:

```
Student s1 = new Student();
s1.setData(1, "Walied");

Student s2 = new Student();
s2.setData(2, "Ayman");

Student s3 = new Student();
s3.setData(3, "Mostafa");

s1.printData();
s2.printData();
s3.printData();
```

In your test class you could save all of your Student objects in a List:

```
List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
studentList.add(s1);
studentList.add(s2);
studentList.add(s3);
```

Then loop through the list and print the data for each object:

```
for (Student s : studentList) {
   s.printData();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `AddStudent` you replace the previous student.
You could create `List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();` instead.
Then add `list.add(s);` where
`Student s = new Student();`

Answer (score 1):

You are only creating 1 object of the type Student. And you are assigning three different values to it. Hence, the first two values get overwritten. If you have three students, you need to create three Student objects.

```
    Student s = new Student();   //Creates a new Student object.
    s.AddStudent(1, "Walied");   //This will assign 1 and Walied as ID and name to the objcet.
    s.AddStudent(2, "Ayman");    // Now again, you are assigning new ID and name to the same object. So the previous value is overwritten.
    s.AddStudent(3, "Mostafa");  // Same effect as above.
```

Hence only the last value is available for you to use.

You can either create three objects of Student type and assign each of them the three values as below.

```
Student s1 = new Student();
Student s2 = new Student();
Student s3 = new Student();
s1.AddStudent(1, "Walied");
s2.AddStudent(2, "Ayman");
s3.AddStudent(3, "Mostafa");
```

And use the print method of each object to print its values

OR

You can create a list of type Student and add the object to it every time you populate it with values as below.

```
 Student s = new Student();
 s.AddStudent(1, "Walied");
```

Now add this to a list of type Student and in the end, iterate through the list and invoke the print method for each object

Answer (score 1):

> *"but i didn't make it print all student it just print the lastest student added im learning java here is my test class"*

You need to put a print statement after each call to `s.AddStudent`

---

**Overall though**, you don't have the greatest design. When thinking about OOP, you need to consider what's what. A `Student` is just one student. So there should be no method to add a student or to print all students. You should create two separate classes:

```
public class Student {
    String name;
    int id;

    public Student(int id, String name){
         this.name = name;
         this.id = id;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Name: " + name + " Id: " + id;
    }
}

public class StudentList {
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public void addStudent(Student student){
        students.add(student);
    }

    public void printAllStudents(){
        for (Student student : students){
            System.out.println(student);
        }
    }
}
```

In you student class, you can get the name and other info. Your `StudentList` class will hold all the students. It should have a method to add a student and a method to print all students.

In your main, you should then create a `StudentList` object and create three `Student` object and add them to the `StudentList` object, then use the print method from the `StudentList` object

```
public static void main(String[] args {
    StudentList studentList = new StudentList();
    studentList.add(new Student(1, "Walied"));
    studentList.add(new Student(2, "Ayman"));
    studentList.add(new Student(3, "Mostafa"));

    studentList.printAllStudents();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You always overwrite the student info with the call to add student. If you just have one ID and one name, and always set those to a new value it replaces the previous information.

You also should not assign the addStudent method to the Student object, as it doesn't relate to a single student but to a collection of students. You could create a class that holds a collection of Student-objects and place it there. You then create a new Student object within addStudent() and place it into the collection.

Answer (score 0):

When you create object you can access it's property, if you want to insert more than one value in to the same property then you need to use List or Map or..... 
so now you create one object with list interface like List listS=new ArrayList();
and you can easily to insert more than one value, without creating more object.